# How to specify in presentation that permission to use a particular image is taken?

Tags: copyright

I am presently undertaking research on a particular topic in control systems. That particular topic has a long history and I found a image which summarizes the history in one image only. I want to use that particular image in my presentation. I have also taken permission from the authors of that image to use it. But, while using it in my slide, I want to show in the same slide that I have taken permission to use that image so that professors understand that I am not stealing that image but I have taken the requisite permission to use that image. What line or a sentence should I include in that particular slide, so that the professors get that point automatically. I mean something like "Used with permissions". Like that what is the precise line which can be included ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When putting / formatting an image on the slide you can normally add a caption box below with the source shown, such as « Used with permission, source Fred Jones, Somewhere, 2018 », also respecting your referencing structure (APA etc).

Answer (score 2):

You can cite it a number of ways. I usually do this:

Right below the image, (Smith et al. 1998) if it's a paper where the image comes from. Then at the end of the presentation, you can have a slide called "References", there you can list the paper in the reference style of your choosing (e.g. APA). This way it's very clear where the image comes from.

I don't think the phrase "used with permissions" is necessary in a presentation. But I'm not certain. I'm sure others will comment on this. However, that phrase IS necessary if you were to publish the slides of your presentation, or if you will use that image in a paper.

Comment: I am not using that image in any paper and I understand that putting it in "References" at the end might be sufficient. But, since it is my final presentation, I don't want to take the risk of making my professors angry. So, I want to use some particular line in the same slide only. Which line should be used, that I am unable to comprehend. It should just show that I have taken permission from xyz person/organisation for using it in my slide